# How to use gstreamer to create a video test pattern to h.264 enc to rtp to pcap?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

I would like to create a H.264 pcap using gstreamer.

Currently, I am stuck here:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay !  udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 ! filesink location=xyz.pcap
```

I get this error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link udpsink0 to filesink0
```